# MYSQL Duplicate records with SELECT DISTINCT

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates, distinct

in mysql I'm getting a duplicate record for the countryCode of USA. I'm using SELECT DISTINCT as per the image attached. I'm not sure why? I have duplicate records for the United Kingdom, but these aren't showing up, which is what I'd expect.

My question is why is it showing up in the USA? The two USA records are the first and last. The first row in the table is Alabama. Not sure if that has anything to do.

Thanks for your help in advance.[image]

Comment: Check if you do not have space or special character in the countryCode column. `SELECT DISTINCT countryCode , LENGTH(countryCode ) from country`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have extra characters that you cannot see.  One possibility are spaces.  You can check if the lengths are the same:

```
select countryCode, char_length(countryCode)
from country
group by countryCode;
```

My guess is that the length will not be 3.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. You were correct all but one had a value of 4. I found it strange and wondered if you had any idea what caused it to be four? I had thought it was white space, but when I opened up the file in excel and notepad, I couldn't see any white space after the USA. Thanks very much.

Comment: @EddieLeach . . . There are lots of hidden characters that can lurk in data.  The most common is a space at the end, but there are others.

Answer (score 0):

Please try using "trim" function:

```
select distinct trim(countryCode) as countryCode
from country
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, this returned the same results.